# Does acuity of a re-mapped region of cortex depend on the need of the animal to resolve between two closely related stimuli?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, senses

From my informal research so far, I've learned that cortical magnification is evident in at least the visual cortex and the somatosensory cortex.

My question is the following:

If there were a hypothetical experiment to be done where the one area of the cortex, say the visual cortex, were to be re-mapped to a different sensory modality like touch, would the acuity or "resolving power" of the re-mapped region depend on the extent to which the animal needed to distinguish between closely related touch stimuli? In other words, has anyone tried an experiment that results in a re-mapped *and* magnified cortical portion in one go?

Comment: Interesting question. I doubt an experiment like this would survive an Institutional Review Board (IRB) review, though, so my guess would be that this hasn't been tried (if it is possible from a surgical perspective).